# how to programatically change keyboard mode in android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-input-method

In my application I have a two buttons which will change the soft input keyboard style to TextMode and Emoji mode. If I press the `TextMode` button , it should change the keyboard style to text mode , similarly `Emoji mode` button will open keyboard with emoji mode. I've given the screenshot of my requirement

[on click of TextMode button (Aa)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuZIw.png)

[on click of Emoji mode button :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgGwR.png)

Is it possible to programatically change the keyboard mode? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looking exactly into the same stuff: not a custom emoji panel but just enabling the built-in one in the softkeyboard when it's opened, no luck so far...

Answer (score 0):

Try this library -

https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

Hope it will help :)